# nginx.conf not properly restarting

Tags: nginx

We had altered our `nginx.conf` file to redirect all urls to their www alternatives. Later, we removed the lines responsible for this functionality. However, even after running `sudo service nginx restart`, the www redirect continues.

Strangely, even when we run `sudo service nginx stop`, the nginx server continues serving. According to `service nginx status`, `nginx is not running`. However, when I run `ps -ef |grep nginx`, there's a line:

```
deploy    1473  1251  0 12:58 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

When I try to kill this with `kill -9 1473`, I get the error:

```
-bash: kill: (1473) - No such process
```

Running `ps -ef |grep nginx` again, I see:

```
deploy    1478  1251  0 12:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

The pid has changed.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not running.  What you're seeing is the grep command that you're executing.  When it's done, the process doesn't exist anymore.  If you replace nginx with any other word (elephant, etc), you'll see the same result.

What error do you see when you try to start nginx?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense now. I wasn't receiving any errors, but I was getting some strange behavior due to a browser cache. Thankfully, it's resolved now.